# BUG: Chrome Inspector blacks out when using border-radius within Cordova Ionic app

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

My Cordova app is all working just fine, been using Chrome Inspector to help troubleshoot and debug all the coding.  Recently I began cleaning up the UI and started incorporating `border-radius` in many locations to clean up buttons, windows, div borders, popups etc.  However, when `border-radius` is specifically applied to Ionic `modals` or Ionic `popovers` it causes Chrome Inspector webview of my app to black out.   Specifically the the app imaging itself...the rest of chrome inspector  (coding, console, elements, etc) is still visible.

I am also testing the app directly on various phones as well, when a modal or popover is enabled on the app it looks just fine on the phone, but its blacked out on Chrome Inspector.  If I go to the CSS element code and disable `border-radius` on that element, the full image of my app reappears in Chrome Inspector.

I have done a few searches for this issue and haven't really turned up anything.  Has anyone seen this before or know of a solution?

Per request:

```
.modal-center{
  width:90%;
  height:80%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
  left:5%;
  right:5%;
  min-height:0;
  border: 2px solid #4e8cf9;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: add your style code

Comment: ok...not certain why adding the code matters...but I did.  With border-radius on a modal/popover, chrome inspector blacks out.  Uncheck border-radius, app image reappears.

Comment: Well i was just wondering if maybe you were referencing a mixin .. maybe incorrectly. But i  guess its just css

Comment: `.modal-center` <- is this a custom class because i dont see a `modal-center` class on the current modal ( ionic 3 )

Comment: Also .. what version of chrome are you using

Comment: It is a custom class.  But I also anticipated it might be my specific CSS.  So I removed my custom class and went directly to the Ionic CSS .modal and added the 'border-radius' there - same issue happened.  It only happens on modals/popovers though - I use 'border-radius' on many other items: buttons, divs, selects, labels, etc...all works/looks fine in chrome inspector....its just with modals and popovers.  I am on Chrome version Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)